# Why is there no 'positionChange' event in Kinetic.js?

Tags: javascript, event-handling, kineticjs

I am trying to do some AngularJS directive with KineticJS. I want a draggable joystick which is a circle in a kinetic canvas, i now want to add a event listener, which should work for touch and mouse. I started trying `touchmove` but that did not work for mouse.

So i took a look at the Object and i realized i can register `xChange` and i can do the same for `yChange`, but why is there no Listener for a `positionChange`? Of course i can register two handlers, but i fear this creates a ton of function calls.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically i can use `dragmove` since the object is draggable and this function works for both touch and mouse

Comment: Note that `dragmove` and `touchmove/mousemove` are not equivalent. For the same functionality in both mobile and desktop, you can listen for `mousemove` and `touchmove` in the same event handler like so: `shape.on("mousemove touchmove", ...)`. On the other hand, if you just want to do something when the joystick is being **dragged** use the `dragmove` event and it will work fr both mobile and desktop as you said.